# Eclipse RCP add log statements from other plug-ins to log plug-in

Tags: eclipse, logging, view, rcp

I would like to show some logging information in my Eclipse RCP application. For this I created a Eclipse view in a separate Plug-in (singleton). Here is my code that I got so far:

```
public class Console extends ViewPart {    
    private StyledText text;

    public Console() {}

    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        text = new StyledText(parent, SWT.READ_ONLY | SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL
                | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    }

    @Override
    public void setFocus() {
        this.text.setFocus();
    }

    public void log(String message){
        this.text.append(message);
    } 
}
```

And the configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
  <extension
        point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
     <view
           category="org.myApp.ui.category.myApp"
           class="org.myApp.ui.log.Console"
           icon="icons/log.png"
           id="org.myApp.ui.view.console"
           name="Console"
           restorable="true">
     </view>
     <category
           id="org.myApp.ui.category.myApp"
           name="myApp">
     </category>
  </extension>
</plugin>
```

Now, I would like to log messages from other plug-ins to the `StyledText` instance. What is the most convenient way to do this?

I tried this [approach](http://waynebeaton.wordpress.com/2006/10/19/displaying-the-console-in-your-rcp-application/) and it's convenient but really really slow. I really appreciate your help :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://ekkescorner.wordpress.com/blog-series/osgi-apps/) is a great series of articles about logging in OSGI.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I had a look and I'm not sure if this fits my needs. I simply want to show some information for the user in a certain view. I personally consider traditional logging where messages with a level are appended to a log file as developer information.

Comment: I haven't used it myself, therefore the link. You can hook into eclipse logging using the org.eclipse.core.runtime.ILogListener interface.

Comment: I checked this and my error log view contains some messages that I don't want to show the user. Isn't there a simple way to pass over a `String` to a certain view instance?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the post-construct method of my console part. Basically it sets a new System.out object and listens to it.

```
@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct(Composite parent) {

    System.out.println("[Console Part] ** Post Construct **"); 

    txtConsole = new Text(parent, SWT.READ_ONLY | SWT.MULTI | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);

    out = new OutputStream() {

        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            if( txtConsole.isDisposed() )
                return;
            txtConsole.append(String.valueOf((char) b));
        }
    };

    // keep the old output stream
    final PrintStream oldOut = System.out;

    System.setOut(new PrintStream(out));
    txtConsole.addDisposeListener(new DisposeListener() {
        public void widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent e) {
            System.setOut(oldOut);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: **ps** I am using Eclipse e4.